# CDI multithreading

Tags: multithreading, jboss7.x, cdi, inject

We want to optimize our application. There is some streight linear work going on, that can be executed in multiple threads with smaller working sets.

Our typical service is accessed using the `@Inject` annotation from within our CDI-managed beans. Also such a service could have it's own dependencies injected, i.e.:

```
public class MyService {

   @Inject
   private OtherService otherService;

   @Inject
   private DataService1 dataService1;

   ...

   public void doSomething() {
     ...
   }
}
```

Because I can not use `@Inject` inside the class implementing `Runnable`. (It's not container managed.) I tried to pass the required services to the class before starting the thread. So, using something like this, makes the service instance (`myService`) available within the thread:

```
Class Thread1 implements Runnable{
   private MyService myService

   public Thread1(MyService myService){
      this.myService = myService;
   }

   public void run(){
      myService.doSomething();
   } 
}
```

Following the call-hierarchy the call to `doStometing()` is fine, because a reference to `myService` has been passed. As far as I understand CDI, the injection is done the moment the attribute is accessed for the first time, meaning, when the `doStomething()` method tries to access either `otherService` or `dataService1`, the injection would be performed.

At that point however I receive an exception, that there is no context available.

I also tried to use the `JBossThreadExecuter` class instead of *Plain-Threads* - it leads to the very same result.

So the question would be, if there is a nice way to associate a context (or request) with a created `Thread`?

For EJB-Beans, I read that marking a method with `@Asynchronous` will cause the method to be run in a *managed thread* which itself will be wired to the context. That would basically be exactly what I'm searching for.

Is there a way to do this in CDI?

Or is there any way to obtain a `context` from within a unmanaged thread?

Comment: What is the scope of the injected service and its dependencies?

Comment: @JohnAment most of them are `@Stateless`. Some are `@RequestScoped`.

Answer (score 4):

Weld allows programmatic context management, [(there's an example in the official docs).](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/contexts.html)

But before you go this way give EJBs a chance )
@Async invocation functionality is there exactly for your case. And as a bonus you'll get timeout interception and transaction management.

Comment: Plus async invocations happen in threads from a configurable thread pool, this makes it much easier to predict and monitor threading behavior.

Answer (score 4):

When you kick off an async process, your `@RequestScoped` and `@SessionScoped` objects are no longer in scope.  That's why you get resolution errors for the injected `@RequestScoped` objects.  Using `@Stateless` without a CDI scope is essentially `@Dependent`.  You can use `@ApplicationScoped` objects or if you're on CDI 1.1 you can start up `@TransactionScoped`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaEE 7 feature, the managed executor. So it will provide a context for your runnable. I'm not sure if your JBoss version is JavaEE 7 compatible. At least Glassfish 4 is, and that approach works.
See details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Solution one can think of is Ejb Async.

They are powerful, does the job and most importantly the concurrency is handled by the container(which could be an issue at some point of time if its not properly managed).

Just a simple use case lets say if we have written a rest service and each request spawns 10 threads(ex using CompletableFuture or anything) to do some long processing tasks and for an instance if 500 requests are made then how will the threads be managed, how the app behaves, does it waits for a thread from the thread pool, what is the timeout period, etc etc and to add to our comfort what happens when the threads are Deamon Threads. We can avoid these overheads to some extent using EJBs.

Its always a good thing to have a friend from the technical services team to help us with all these container specific implementations.