# Inject Context (CDI/servlet) into new FutureTask Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, cdi, futuretask

I found that a new thread created in the servlet donot contain the servlet/CDI context. I created a HelloWorld servlet (given below) to experiment with this problem. In the below example, you'll see that I am running 'doIt()' function in a new Thread (FutureTask). But it returns NULL but when I call 'doIt()' method directly, BeanManager is not NULL.

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class
            .getName());

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.println("<html>");
        writer.println("<head><title>Hello World Servlet</title></head>");
        writer.println("<body>");
        writer.println("<h1>Context injection into Thread Experiment</h1>");
        try {
            // 1. This is NOT working
            new Thread(testTask).start();
            testTask.get(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // 2. This is working
                //doIt();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        writer.println("<body>");
        writer.println("</html>");
        writer.close();         
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                doIt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    FutureTask<Object> testTask = new FutureTask<Object>(runnable, null);

    protected void doIt() throws Exception {
        if(getBeanManager() == null) { 
            throw new Exception( "BEAN MANAGER IS NULL"); 
        }
    }

    public static BeanManager getBeanManager() {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            return (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.info("Couldn't get BeanManager through JNDI");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I searched online but could not find a good reference than saying it is possible. It would be great, if anybody can help me or provide me with some good pointers to inject/pass context into the new thread.

Comment: Yes, this looks awkward but I need this for my own logic and project requirement. This is just an example. That is why I am interested in knowing whether I can do this way or not. Similar to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284191/cdi-multithreading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using EJB 3.1 and Java EE 6 or greater, the notation [`@Asynchronous`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) on a method makes it run in a separate thread and takes care of managing resources, etc.

If you need more control, as pointed out by Kalpesh Soni, [this answer describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404307/1270789) how to use [`ManagedExecutorService`](https://concurrency-ee-spec.java.net/javadoc/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html), if you have Java EE 7 or greater.

Additionally, I'm not sure if you really need that `getBeanManager()` static method - wouldn't just `@EJB BeanManager beanManager;` (or `@Inject`) suffice?

Answer (score 1):

the container must be cleaning up the servlet object after the request is over

The thread should create its own resources

by the way, if you use container (tomcat/weblogic/websphere) it does some extra things to set up transactional context, which is NOT available to your own threads

its best not to mix thread api with java ee

[Java EE specification and multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212255/java-ee-specification-and-multi-threading)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a solution to the problem I asked in this question. The question was solved with the help of answers given here. I think, this answer would help other developers in future. My main aim was to get a timeout of a function or

I used *@Asyncronous* on method to run in separate thread which also contains the CDI context. By using `.get(timeout, TimeUnit)`, I set timeout parameter for the task which runs '*Future*' task.

Following is the code of the Helloworld servlet which runs the task and gets the timeout if it runs more than the expected time to finish the work.

```
@WebServlet(value = "/HelloWorld", asyncSupported = true)
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class
            .getName());

    @Inject doItWithAsync doAsync;
    @Inject doItWithAsync doAsyncTimeout;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<html>");
        writer.println("<head><title>Hello World Servlet</title></head>");
        writer.println("<body>");
        writer.println("<h1>New Thread with Context Experiment</h1>");
        try {
            String ret1 = doAsync.doItAsync().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            writer.println("<h2>Result1: "+ ret1+"</h2>");
            String ret2 = doAsyncTimeout.doItAsync().get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            writer.println("<h2>Result2: "+ ret2+"</h2>");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            writer.println("<h2>Timeout Exception: "+ e.getMessage()+"</h2>");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println("<body>");
        writer.println("</html>");
        writer.close();         
    }

    public static BeanManager getBeanManagerFromInitialContext() {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            return (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.info("Couldn't get BeanManager through JNDI");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The separate function or task which should be running in separate thread for timeout check is implemented in different class as @stateless session beans.

```
@Stateless
public class doItWithAsync {

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> doItAsync() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String result;
        if(HelloWorld.getBeanManagerFromInitialContext() == null) { 
            throw new Exception( "BEAN MANAGER IS NULL !"); 
        } else {
            result = "OK Async!!";
        }

        return new AsyncResult<String>(result);
    }
}
```

The **output** would look like this:

```
New Thread with Context
Result1: OK Async!!
Timeout Exception: JBAS014334: Task did not complete in 2 SECONDS
```